# Permissions always returns "Granted" for Permissions.Photos in .net MAUI

Tags: maui

I am using below code to access gallery permissions in .net maui but it always returns Granted even on first time launch of the application and I am not able to see the permission popup saying **"This app would like to access photos and media on your device"**

```
public static async Task<PermissionStatus> GetMediaPermissionStatus()
        {
            PermissionStatus mediaResult = PermissionStatus.Disabled;
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PermissionStatus>();
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Photos>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Photos>();
            }
            tcs.SetResult(status);
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
```

Also when I execute below code getting 2 app permission Popups
1st Popup - "Allow application to take pictures and record video"
2nd Popup - "Allow application to access photos and media on your device?"

```
public async void TakePhoto()
{
    if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
    {
        FileResult photo = await Microsoft.Maui.Media.MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();

        if (photo != null)
        {
            // save the file into local storage
            string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

            using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
            using FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);

            await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is a bug or I am doing something wrong.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this doc: [Permissions of MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android). There is a table in it.  It uses ✔️ to indicate that the permission is supported and ❌ to indicate the permission isn't supported or isn't required

> If a permission is marked as ❌, it will always return `Granted` when checked or requested.

> `Granted`:
> The user granted permission or is automatically granted.

Wish it can help you.

Comment: Any idea why we are getting 2 app permission Popups while accessing Camera and is there any other way to request app permission while accessing gallery in MAUI

Comment: @Mars The reason why 2nd app permission Popups is that you save the file into local storage. I tested the code you provided. And the permission request will pop up when running for the first time, and the dialog box will not pop up when running again.